# how can I add auth to my django project's sphinx docs?

Tags: django, authorization, python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx-apidoc to auto-generate documentation for my Django project which is using django-social-auth + oauth2 for auth.  I want to be able to use that same auth to access the documentation.  How can I do this?

I've looked into [django-sphinxdoc](http://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/django-sphinxdoc/), but the current version isn't compatible with the latest Haystack and seems to have some other bugs.  Plus, do I really need to do something like it does - convert the docs into JSON and store them into the DB in order to render in a template context?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the sphinx build static html files to your django web-server project as static files and simple add user auth this static files route.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  How would you write that route?  You need a view for a route and then you're no longer serving a static file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_wsgi's `WSGIAuthUserScript` directive to call the Django backend for authentication. This way you have a HTTP BASIC AUTH with Django's user database as backend.

See the [modwsgi documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms) and [check_password()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/handlers/modwsgi.py#L6)

**EDIT:**

I just noticed there's a comprehensive [How To](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/) in the Django documentation about this.